# get rid of the text area on a form once clicked

Tags: javascript, html

my javascript gives a estimate for name plates 
each letter is $10

Very new to Javascript, I am trying to get rid of the text Area on my input/display once the submit/button is clicked. . . .  lets just say if I want to re-enter an input it should clear the last input and give new price . . . right now is piling up

for example : Enter Name: Total Cost is $30Total Cost is $60Total Cost is $60Total Cost is $90Total Cost is $110Total Cost is $140

```
<body>
<div id='container' > 
    <div id='banner'> 
          <h4 id='signName'>Name Plate Estimate</h4>
    </div>
          <p id="enterName">Enter Name: </p> 

    <div id='form'>
          <form>
              <input id="userInput" name="userInput" type="text" />
    <br>
          </form>

    </div>
       <button id="button">Show Cost</button>
</div> 



</body>
```

heres my javascript ;

```
document.getElementById('button').onfocus = function(){

var userText = document.getElementById('userInput').value ; 


var cost = 10 ;
var price = function(){

 var total = userText.length * cost;
  return total ; 
}  


if (userText.length === 0){

  var elError = document.getElementById('enterName') ; 
  elError.innerHTML += "Please enter a valid name" ; 
} else {

  var elErrror = document.getElementById('enterName') ; 
  elErrror.innerHTML += 'Total Cost is $'  + price() ; 



}

}
```

Comment: Are you looking to empty the input area?

Comment: Yes , you can take a look at what I mean here enter multiple names  http://output.jsbin.com/gikomukaro

Comment: @velimir got it working...

Comment: no it doesnt work i only need to post 1 output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending the new data to your element with `+=`, you want to replace the whole innerHTML, so just use the `=` operator.

```
elErrror.innerHTML += 'Total Cost is $'  + price() ;
```

becomes

```
elErrror.innerHTML = 'Total Cost is $'  + price() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information please take a look at this link hopefully you can better assist me. . .  enter multiple names  http://output.jsbin.com/gikomukaro

Comment: @MarkeseP Have you tried the change suggested? It works fine after you use the suggested change.

Comment: Thanks I see whats your saying now , yes I was appending it to the" Enter Name: " instead of creating a whole new element so I will assume thats very bad practice

Comment: it does work but if I were to append it how would I clear the text ?

Comment: to append is not a bad practice, it's just not what you want. Also you are not creating a new element, rather you just change the value of the already existing element (to create a new one would be a bad practice since it is obsolete)

Comment: Thanks brother for the advice/help . . . really really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Please add below script:

```
document.getElementById('userInput').onfocus = function(){
  document.getElementById('userInput').value = ''
};
```

Comment: It will resolve your issue of clearing text input when you try to add new value.